# WCF and client code

Tags: wcf, client

I am beginner in WCF. I have two simple services: adding client first and last name, and returning number of clients. When I test the service to the client whenever a customer adds, the number is not increasing is always one. Here code:

```
class ClientService : IClientService
{
   List<Client> list = new List<Client>();

   public bool SubmitClient(Client client)
   {
      list.Add(client);
   }

   public int IClientService.GetClient()
   {
      return list.Count;
   }
}
```

Client code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ClientServiceClient channel = new ClientServiceClient();
   Client cl = new Client();
   cl.FirstName = txtFName.Text;
   cl.LastName = txtLName.Text;

   channel.SubmitClient(cl);
   labbel1.Text=string.Format("Number of clients: {0}"),channel.GetClient());
}
```

Comment: The default instance context mode of WCF service is PerCall means everytime you make a service call a new instance is created in the server, the old state is completely forgotten

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the [InstanceContextMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.instancecontextmode.aspx) value in the ServiceBehavior attribute. The prolbem is that your list is a class level variable, you need to configure the WCF service as Single instance mode.

- **PerSession(default)**: a new InstanceContext object is created for each session.
- **PerCall**: a new InstanceContext object is created prior to and recycled subsequent to each call.
- **Single**: only one InstanceContext object is used for all incoming calls and is not recycled subsequent to the calls.

Here is a good link on the subject of control the WCF instances/sessions:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/86007/3-ways-to-do-WCF-instance-management-Per-call-Per